# Python sys.argv[0] not showing -c value

Tags: python, python-3.x, command

New to Python and started from the documentation linearly:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html

> If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.

My code:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

My command:

```
py main.py -c test
```

Output:

```
['main.py', '-c', 'test']
```

So it appears even tho I entered -c test sys.argv[0] value is 'main.py', while documentation states it should be '-c'.

So '-c' here is actually sys.argv[1].

Python version: 3.7.3.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why don't you use Argparse https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: I'm not using Python, this is just for education purposes. Trying to figure out how things exactly work. Seems something's not right here in my code/setup or something. I'll check that out as well tho, thanks!

Comment: Try `python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"`. As per the doc "A second way of starting the interpreter is `python -c command [arg] ...,`  **which executes the statement(s) in command**"

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Aha got it. You may submit this as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: In `sys.argv` first value is always name of executed python module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the option `-c` needs to be in first position.

I tried to create a simple script `test.py`:

```
print('foo')
```

If you run `python test.py test.py`, you will see only one `foo`, which means the second `test.py` gets ignored. This is the same for your example `py main.py -c test`

This is not very clear in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing), but I think this the spirit:

> ### 2.1.1. Argument Passing
>
> When known to the interpreter, the script name and additional arguments thereafter are turned into a list of strings and assigned to the argv variable in the sys module. You can access this list by executing import sys. The length of the list is at least one; when no script and no arguments are given, sys.argv[0] is an empty string. When the script name is given as '-' (meaning standard input), sys.argv[0] is set to '-'. When -c command is used, sys.argv[0] is set to '-c'. When -m module is used, sys.argv[0] is set to the full name of the located module. Options found after -c command or -m module are not consumed by the Python interpreter’s option processing but **left in sys.argv for the command or module to handle.**

So the correct usage is `python -c "cmd"` and not `python file.py -c file2.py`.

Answer (score 0):

A second way of starting the interpreter is python -c command [arg] ..., which executes the statement(s) in command.

-c is not passing the '-c' string to the program as argument, it's executing a statement in the command, by example:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"
```

In sys.argv first value is always name of executed python module, either the filename or command.